# Is possibile to create an Alpine.js component without a "real" HTML element?

Tags: alpine.js

I'd like to create an Alpine.js 3 component (i.e. assign `x-data`) to a wrapper element, without create an HTML element that will be "outputted". In order words, I want two child to share the same data, without forcing a given html element as root (`<div>`, `<span>`, set...)

Take the [collapse example](https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/collapse), the root component is `div`:

```html
<div x-data="{ expanded: false }">
    <button @click="expanded = ! expanded">Toggle Content</button>
 
    <p x-show="expanded" x-collapse>
        ...
    </p>
</div>
```

Since my component could be shared and reused, it would be nice to not force the outer `<div>` element.

This is **not working** (no output at all):

```html
<template x-data="{ expanded: false }">
    <button @click="expanded = !expanded">Collapse</button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can share a state between sibling components via the global [`$store` object](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store):

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@alpinejs/collapse@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.store('expanded', false)
})
</script>


<button x-data @click="$store.expanded = ! $store.expanded">Toggle Content</button>

<div x-data x-show="$store.expanded" x-collapse>Content</div>
```

Alternatively you can use events as well, i.e. one component emits an `expanded` event and the other component listens to it and mutates its local `expanded` property (same with a `collapsed` event).